# Google Maps works in debug not in apk

Tags: android, google-maps

I added a map to a layout with a text view on top of it. In debug when I run the app on my phone the map comes up as expected. I pass my current longitude and latitude to the intent and the map centers on my location. The text view is visible and I can drop and pin and get the new coordinates.

I wanted to share the apk with someone so I first generated the file and emailed it to myself. After downloading and installing on my phone as a test I noticed the map no longer displays. There are no exceptions thrown. The text view is visible and the small 'Google' logo is in the bottom right, so the map there, but it is just a white screen. There is no map image. I tried to pinch thinking I am too zoomed in or out, but nothing changes.

Below is the layout of the activity. When I view it in design mode there is rendering problem. Part of the output from the rendering exception is below. the exception was 1025 lines long, which made it too long for a SO post. It was a lot of repeat, so i cut it down. I'm not sure if the two issues are related.

Is there anything wrong with my layout that would account for the problems? The phone shows that the app has the correct permissions for Location services.

I'm in Android Studio 1.4.0/ SDK 23

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapActivity" >
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"     tools:context=".GarbageLocator"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_garbage_locator" />
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ItemName"
        android:text="@string/hunt_item"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"

        android:textSize="32sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>



java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getSystemProperty(SecuritySupport.java:62)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:229)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:120)
at com.android.utils.XmlUtils.parseDocument(XmlUtils.java:432)
at com.android.utils.XmlUtils.parseDocumentSilently(XmlUtils.java:484)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.findCycles(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:397)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.getParser(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:315)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.getParser(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:306)
at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getLayout(BridgeResources.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:135)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:879)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:831)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:197)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:879)
```

Comment: I will add that I have cleaned, rebuilt, and reinstalled twice. Issue persists.

Comment: Are you using a different certificate for the APK?  If so, did you add that certificate's fingerprint on the Google API console?

Comment: I created a new certificate when I created the apk and continue to use it for each build. How do I add the certificate to the Google API console. I assumed the installation took care of certificates.

Comment: Ok, yes i did get a new API key for Google Maps from developers console. I thought you meant the certificate used when distributing the APK.

Comment: I followed instructions here (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en) to generate a new key based on the fingerprint of the cert used in release. I added the new API based on the fingerprint to google_maps_api.xml, replacing the other one I had gotten. Clean, built, released, and installed. Same problem exists. Map activity appears with the Google logo as if it is a map, but no map image appears.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the mystery solved. The rendering problem is because when I clicked on the design tab AS asked me to choose which layout I wanted to display in the fragment, so I chose the layout for the activity. AS then added the line 'tools:layout="@layout/activity_garbage_locator"' to the layout, which I guess caused a sort of circular reference. Ugh!

Also, after adding the new API key the map no longer works in either Debug or Release. Consistency in failure is progress, I guess. I added a new activity with a Google map and ran it as-is, that is to say, without any additional code, and it won't display a map either. I get the same thing: an off-white screen with the Google logo in the bottom left. Just as I would get if there was a map, but no map.

In my original activity with code to trap the longitude and latitude of a dropped pin, the map actually does work in that it returns a new longitude and latitude when I tap on the screen. It just doesn't show the stupid map!

Greg

Comment: Have you added the fingerprint of the new key and the package name here? https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: Is that different than this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en See my comment above

Comment: It's part of that, yes.  I was asking about the middle part where you add the fingerprint and package name to your API key.  Did you do that?  You described getting the key and adding it to your app, but if you don't also enter the key and package on the developer console the map will fail in exactly the way you describe.

Comment: Yep, did it. Used keytool to get fingerprint, and added it and package name to the console. I also imported in an activity from another app that uses a map that works, but in my new app has the same problem. I also tried using the API key from the working app in the new app and it fails the display the map, as well.

Comment: Anything in the logcat?  Often it will give you some information about authorization failure.

Comment: See answer above. There was something in logcat. Not sure how I missed before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was an API issue, but I'm not really sure what was going on. I tried several different things after reading several different posts regarding this problem. I think what fixed it was hard coding the API key in the manifest, as one post suggested.

Original manifest entry

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Change to

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIz_MY_ACTUAL_KEY" />
```